# Suffering siblings abuse

Tags: relationships, family, violence

Is there somebody who can help me. I am really going through a hard phase both financially and emotionally
My sister has made my life a living hell
She always fights with me and God forbid if i say something in my defense she makes a big issue out of it. Slandering my character has become her favourite hobby and not to mention the physical abuse she does with me. Few months back she slapped me on my face  and kicked me in the belly. I cannot forget that trauma to this day. Plz help me i am so scared adn after all this she stops talking with me as if i have done something wrong with her. For sometime i think it's good she stopped talking because i want to maintain a distance for now because wallahi right from childhood she has made my life miserable. Not only she fights with me she fights with our parents and other siblings also and I don't know why she becomes so violent and starts hitting even parents
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I'm so sorry for what is happening. I don't have the best advice as I am stuck with toxic siblings too but thats why I wanted to send you a messege to let you know you're not alone.
InShaAllah your relief and happiness is coming very soon. Make Dua to Allah swt he will resolve everything. Ask him in Tahajjud. Until then I know it can be hard and confusing. Physical abuse is especially not okay, you can certainly report her if the abuse endangers you.
Also whereever you live search for a local free therapy service. Sometimes toxic family members can make you feel worthless and the cause of everything but as soon as you speak with people outside of the situation you will gain clarity and confidence in your sanity. And the emotional, mental and physical toll of your situation the therapist may help. If you cant find a therapist book a doctors appointment and ask for any kind of help.

May Allah swt help you swiftly Ameen!